2 notice periods in my contract - redundancy query
We have been notified of imminent redundancies at my place of work, I have only been there 1y 8m. I (perhaps wrongly) assumed they would need to give me 3 months notice as it’s in my contract. I have to give 3
Months notice to them. However, they advised they only need to give a week, I double checked the contract and have pasted the contract section below. I assume it means I have had to give them 3 months notice to leave but then they have only ever had to give me 1 week (up to 2 years) and then an extra week for every year after that! I missed this when I signed the contract clearly, as usually, I’ve had both myself and employer just having a 1 month rule matches. So when I noted the 3 months notice, I accepted it and assumed if I was made redundant at any point then they would also have to give me 3 months notice. It is excessively unfair they expect 3 months notice from me but then they can make me redundant at the drop of a hat with 1 weeks notice.
This is what it states in the contract
Can you please advise if it is correct they only need to give me 1 weeks notice or where redundancy is concerned should would they need to give my contractual notice of 3 months - this is the U.K.
10. Notice Periods

10.1. On completion of the probationary period and up to two years of employment you will be
entitled to one week’s notice. After the completion of two years continuous employment
you will be entitled to a further week per completed year of service up to a maximum of 12
weeks after 12 completed years.

10.2 On completion of the probationary period you will be required to give the Company three
months’ notice should you wish to terminate your employment. All notifications of
termination must be put in writing to your line manager.

10.3 The Company reserves the right to pay you a payment equal to the remuneration due for
the relevant period of notice rather than requiring you to work your notice period.


What's your question? This is the contract you've signed; I don't see anything illegal about it as it was very clearly stated what the terms are, and you've accepted them.

I didn’t state there was anything illegal about it?? Everything online states the “contractual notice period” overrides the statutory notice period - there are 2 contractual notice periods in my contract, mine & theirs…….are they supposed to use mine or theirs for redundancy (I would expect theirs for termination due to other reasons but when redundancy I’m not sure)

The contract says they will  use theirs (or longer) when letting you go, and that you will use yours (or longer) when leaving by your own choice. Asymmetry is uncommon but not unheard-of.

Thank you for the clarification Keshlam. I didn't realise it was in relation to redundancy as well (I assumed it was just termination for other reasons, ie misconduct) - lesson learned for the future!

“On completion of the probationary period and up to two years of employment you will be
entitled to one week’s notice.” - 20 months is less than 2 years. So you are per your contract only entitled a notice period of one week.  This goes both ways by the way.

Under UK law, it is permitted to have different notice periods for the employer and the employee. I could not find anything that dictates that the notice period of the employer must be at least as long as the notice period of the employee.
The periods mentioned in sections 10.1 and 10.2 of your contract are within the statutory limits that I could quickly find. The contract is clearly in favor of the employer, but there is nothing illegal or unenforceable in it.
So yes, you will only get 1 week notice from your employer for being made redundant.

I checked a site giving advice to companies. They said: 1. Many employees will find different notice periods unfair and won’t accept them. 2. 1 week only is dangerous for you if they don’t think their job is safe and they look elsewhere, but would stay if there were four weeks, being more protected. 3. Three months notice when an employee absolutely doesn’t want to stay isn’t helpful to you. You don’t want to employ and pay someone who doesn’t want to be there, so agree to less if they really want to leave.

Companies sometimes put things in contracts that are legally "iffy" hoping that you won't question them. (For example, it's my understanding that, at least in Ireland, clauses that prevent you from working for competitor after you leave the company may not be enforceable.) I have no idea if this falls into that category, but since it does seem unfair, I think it would be worth checking this with a solicitor. If you call, they may be able to give you a quick answer over the phone for no charge.
